# Why set of natural numbers with its customary ordering by magnitude is not a totally ordered set?

Tags: set-theory, natural-numbers

I'm learning set theory by using Halmos's book. In the section about order, the author states that "The set of all natural numbers (with its customary ordering by magnitude) is an example of a partially ordered set with a first element (which is 0) but no last".

As I understand, we can compare every 2 natural numbers, so the set of all natural numbers must be totally ordered. Could you please explain me why it should be the case as stated by Halmos ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: The natural numbers are indeed totally ordered.  Any subset of the reals is totally ordered.  The quote you mentioned just says there is no greatest natural number, though there is a least natural number, which is certainly true.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me what does it mean by saying "ordering by magnitude" in the statement of Halmos ? Moreover, if I replace "partially ordered" in the statement of Halmos by "totally ordered", is the statement always true ? Thanks!!

Comment: I presume the author is referring to the usual ordering on $\mathbb N$. The only difference between partial and total ordering is that the latter requires that any two elements be comparable under the order, which is certainly true in this case.  Thus, you can indeed make the same claim with "totally" replacing "partially".